# Break a screen flow into 2 transactions

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have read this post already: [Breaking a flow into 2 different transactions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261532/breaking-a-flow-into-2-different-transactions) .

Our scenario is pretty much the same, we need to break the flow into two transactions but it is a screen flow which doesn't have the pause logic available. So is there a way to break screen flow into 2 transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat here that this is a workaround/hack and that we should really be pushing Salesforce for better ways to efficiently bulkify Flows.

That out of the way:

A "Flow Action" (formerly known as a "Local Action") is a lightning component with no UI available to Flows for the purpose of executing javascript locally on the client side during a flow. When one of these executes, it will also commit any pending transaction and then anything after it will be in a new transaction.

The component does not need to do anything to break a transaction, it just needs to execute. For example:

ExampleComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions">
  <!-- this type of component doesn't support UI elements, as you don't use it 
       on a screen in a flow, you use it as an action element between screens or 
       other elements. You can declare attributes or import a library, however -->
</aura:component>
```

ExampleComponentController.js

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        /* when this component is executed, this "invoke" method is called
         * in this case, we dont need to execute anything, we'll just leave it empty
         */
    }
})
```

Then, in your flow, add an "Action" element where you want to break your transaction, and select this Flow Action.

More details on Flow Actions:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:availableForFlowActions/documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_actions.htm

Answer (score 1):

The only two things that can reasonably break a flow into two (or more) transactions are either a Screen or a Pause. As such, you'd probably want a "please continue to finish" type of Screen element. While unfortunate, these are really the only tools we can use (aside from an Apex action that calls a future method) that we can use.

Comment: Got it, it is a login flow so I will probably be using the future method approach then. Thanks